How can I add multiple files to one field through the form?
I need help setting up a form in CRAFT CMS. There is a form:
<form id="add" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ csrfInput() }}
    {{ actionInput('families/families/start') }}
    <div class="fields-boxes">
        <div class="field">
            <input type="text" name="name">
        </div>
        <div class="file-field">
            <input type="file" name="img" />
        </div>
        <div class="submit-form">
            <input type="submit" value="GO">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

And there is her controller:
<?php
namespace modules\families\controllers;

use Craft;
use craft\web\Controller;
use craft\elements\Asset;
use craft\helpers\Assets;
use craft\web\UploadedFile;
use craft\elements\Entry;

class FamiliesController extends Controller
{

    protected array|bool|int $allowAnonymous = true;

    public function actionStart() {
        
        $host = Craft::$app->request->hostInfo;

        $name = $this->request->getBodyParam('name');

        $entryes = Entry::find()->section('familySeason')->phoneFamily($phone)->anyStatus()->all();

        if(count($entryes) == 0){
            $uploadedFile = UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('img');
            $tempPath = $uploadedFile->saveAsTempFile();
            $volume = Craft::$app->getVolumes()->getVolumeByHandle('uploads');
            $folder = Craft::$app->getAssets()->ensureFolderByFullPathAndVolume('family-photos', $volume, false);
            $asset = new Asset();
            $asset->newFolderId = $folder->id;
            $asset->volumeId = $volume->id;
            $asset->tempFilePath = $tempPath;
            $asset->setFilename(Assets::prepareAssetName($uploadedFile->name)); 
            $asset->avoidFilenameConflicts = true;
            $asset->setScenario(Asset::SCENARIO_CREATE);
            if(($uploadedFile->size > 10000000) || ($uploadedFile->type != 'image/jpeg') && ($uploadedFile->type != 'image/png')){
                $redirectUrl = $host."/family/error";
            }else{
                $success = Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($asset);
                if($success){
                    $family = new Entry();
                    $family->sectionId = 7;
                    $family->enabled = false;
                    $family->title = $name;
                    $family->setFieldValue('imageFamily', [$asset->id]);
                    $success = Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($family);
                    $redirectUrl = $host."/family/lucky";
                }
            }
        }else{
            $redirectUrl = $host."/family/error";
        }
        Craft::$app->getResponse()->redirect($redirectUrl);
    }
}

How can I make sure that the user has the opportunity to add several photos and not just one? Is it possible to do this with a single input or is it necessary to produce several? What needs to be tweaked in the form and in the controller to make it work?
What i try to do:
$files = array();
$status = true;

foreach(UploadedFile::getInstancesByName('img') as $uploadedFile){
    $tempPath = $uploadedFile->saveAsTempFile();
    array_push($files,  $uploadedFile);
    $volume = Craft::$app->getVolumes()->getVolumeByHandle('uploads');
    $folder = Craft::$app->getAssets()->ensureFolderByFullPathAndVolume('family-photos', $volume, false);
    if(($uploadedFile->size > 10000000) || ($uploadedFile->type != 'image/jpeg') && ($uploadedFile->type != 'image/png')){
        $status = false;
    }
    array_push($files, $uploadedFile);
}

if($status){
    $ids = array();
    foreach($files as $uploadedFile){
        $asset = new Asset();
        $asset->newFolderId = $folder->id;
        $asset->volumeId = $volume->id;
        $asset->tempFilePath = $tempPath;
        $asset->setFilename(Assets::prepareAssetName($uploadedFile->name)); 
        $asset->avoidFilenameConflicts = true;
        $asset->setScenario(Asset::SCENARIO_CREATE);
        $success = Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($asset);
        array_push($ids,  $asset->id);
    }
    $family = new Entry();
    $family->sectionId = 7;
    $family->enabled = false;
    $family->title = $name;
    $family->setFieldValue('phoneFamily', $phone);
    $family->setFieldValue('imageFamily', [$asset->id]);
    $success = Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($family);
    $redirectUrl = $host."/family/lucky";
}else{
    $redirectUrl = $host."/family/error";
}
Craft::$app->getResponse()->redirect($redirectUrl);

I tried to replace UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('img') with UploadedFile::getInstancesByName('img').
And the first problem I encountered is that the UploadedFile::getInstancesByName('img') construct returns me an array, but always with one element.
My input looks like this:
<input id="file-upload" type="file" name="img" multiple="multiple" />

I select several files, but there is always one picture in UploadedFile::getInstancesByName('img')! Perhaps this is the reason why my code is not working properly. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?! Thank you all in advance)

Have you tried naming your field img[]? So something like this...
<input id="file-upload" type="file" name="img[]" multiple="multiple" />
There's a bit more info on this answer here. That should hopefully get you to where you need to be.
